# WIF Claim/User relationship table

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, wif, claims-based-identity

I'm using WIF in a project but I don't see a built in feature that would allow me to define a preset of claims that are table driven.

I want to define my role claims and do a relationship with the users table. I want the ability to create users in my web app and assign access rules to them based on those claims. Kind of like the CMS type of authorization.

Am I missing anything in WIF? I don't see an AspNetClaims table with a many to many relationship with the AspNetUsers table!!

Answer (score 0):

All the claims in WIF derive from the fact that they are generated by a STS e.g. ADFS. These are in turn derived from AD.

The roles etc. in this case are provisioned in AD.

You can also augment the claims in the CAM in WIF.

If you want to use ASP.NET Identity, look at [Identity Server 3](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/) with the ASP.NET Identity plugin.

Comment: I can't use ADFS or identity server. My API is my STS.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using WIF?

Comment: I have a web api with multiple UI clients. Currently we can't setup and STS so the web api is our STS.